# Set is not inserting

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a problem where my code just seems to get stuck when trying to insert into a set.

```
using namespace std;
set<string> * lexset;


void build( const set<string>& word_list )
   set<string>::iterator it = word_list.begin();

   while( it != word_list.end()) 
   {
      cout << *it << "before"<< endl;
      lexset->insert(*it);
      cout << "after" <<endl;

      ++it;
      cout << "end of while" <<endl;
   }
}
```

It seems to get stuck before the line that prints out 'after'.

The line before insertion prints out a string and I know for sure that wordlist contains a lot of words. This compiles and doesn't loop. If I remove the insert, it iterates through just fine. Why is this insert causing so much trouble?

Comment: Have you   new memory for lexset? and why should lexset be a pointer to a set?

Comment: Have you had `lexset` initialized properly? As you're using a pointer, when is it assigned?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147331). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate memory first for `lexset` :

`lexset = new set<string>;`

And fix your `word_list` typo